# How to show a button as effect while hovering over an image?

Tags: html, css, button, hover, web-frontend

I have an image(class photo) in my webpage and a button(class btn) named "Add to Cart". I want it to work such that when someone hovers over the product image, the "Add to cart" button starts showing over the image while the opacity of the image decreases a bit. I cant quite figure out how to make the button appear when i hover over the image. I am quite new to web development so please help. What do i write in css such that the button is only visible on top of the image when mouse is being hovered over the image.

```
    <div>
        <img class="Photo">
        <button class= "btn">
    <div>
    <style>
        .btn:hover{
        }
    <style
```

Comment: Post a code snippet a least please

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect the image (`class="photo"`) and the button (`class="btn"`) you need some form of container (e.g. a `div` element with `class="container"`) that contains both.

You can then use the `transition` css property, to do the smooth switch of opacity:

```
.btn {
  display: none;
}

.container:hover .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.container:hover .photo {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```